# jquery .hover .animation use to switch between a stack of z-index arranged images

Tags: jquery, css, animation, z-index

**Part A**

**I have the following:**

```
<div class="graphic fadehover" class="last">                
<img src="graphic5test image" alt="" class="a" />
<img src="graphic5-2test image" alt="" class="b" />
</div>
```

**with attached css**

```
.fadehover {display: block; height: 162px; margin: 70px 45px 0 0; position:relative;       width: 292px; z-index: 100; }
img.a {position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 10;}
img.b {position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;}
```

**and this script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("img.a").hover(
function() {
$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
},
function() {
$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
});

});
```

**I would then like to re-use the script on the following:**

```
<div class="animation" class="fadehover">

    <img src="/sun-low image" alt="sun rising" class=""/>
    <img src="/sun-hi image" alt="sun rising" class=""/>        
    <img src="/sun-hi image" alt="sun rising" class=""/>        
</div>
```

**with attached css:**

```
.animation {position: absolute; left: 675px; top: 10px; z-index: 25; } /*positions     sunrise and hills */

.hills{position: absolute; left: 340px; z-index: 50; }

img.e {position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 10;}
img.f {position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index:2; }
```

I know the image links above are wrong but because I'm a newbie stackoverflow won't let me post with them intact.

I would like to re-use the script or a variation of it to be able to fade between the three z-index arranged images (of a sun rising) but don't know how to get a duplicate version of the script to target the new img classes.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for this?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you going to cycle between the three images? I mean are all three going to fade in and out in a repeating cycle as you hover over them, or cycle through each time you `mouseover` and `mouseout`?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't quite sure what you wanted, so I did both.

If a `fadehover` block also has the `animation` class, then it will cycle through all the images inside every 1.5 seconds while you hover over the block. Without the `animation` class, the image will just change to the next one.

I hope all the comments are clear enough so you can understand what I was doing in the script. Oh, and here is [a demo of the whole thing](http://jsfiddle.net/2RbtW/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 // make first image in each block the current image & hide the rest
 $(".fadehover").each(function(){
  $(this).find("img:first").addClass("current");
  $(this).find("img:not(:first)").hide();
 });

 // display next image
 var timer,
  nextImg = function(el) {
   // fadeout current image
   var curImg = el.find('img.current')
    .removeClass('current')
    .stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow');
   // find next image; if no next image exist, reset to the first one
   curImg = (curImg.next().length) ? curImg.next() :  curImg.parent().find('img:first');
   // fadein current (next) image
   curImg
    .addClass('current')
    .fadeIn('slow');
  };

 // cycle through each image on hover
 $(".fadehover").hover(function(){
   var el = $(this);

   // if the fadehover has the animation class, then cycle through the images while hovering
   if (el.is('.animation')) {
    timer = setInterval(function(){ nextImg(el); }, 1500);
   }
   // no animation, just show the next image on hover
   nextImg(el);

  }, function(){
   var el = $(this);

   // on mouseout, stop animation, or do nothing
   if (el.is('.animation')) {
    clearInterval(timer);
   }
   // fadeIn, just in case the clearInterval breaks the animation
   el.find('.current').stop(true, true).fadeIn('slow');

  });

});
```

---

Update ([new demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2RbtW/4/))

Now that I understand what you need, try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 // make first image in each block the current image & hide the rest
 $(".fadehover").each(function(){
  $(this).find("img:first").addClass("current");
  $(this).find("img:not(:first)").hide();
 });

 // display next image
 var timer,
  nextImg = function(el) {
   // fadeout current image
   var curImg = el.find('img.current')
   // find next image; if no next image exist, add "done" class
   if (curImg.next().length) {
    // fadein current (next) image
    curImg
     .removeClass('current')
     .stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow')
     .next()
     .addClass('current')
     .fadeIn('slow');
   } else {
    el.addClass('done');
   }

  };

 // cycle through each image on hover
 $(".fadehover").hover(function(){
   var el = $(this);
   // if the element has the "done" class, then stop
   if (!el.is('done')) {
    timer = setInterval(function(){ nextImg(el); }, 2000);
   }
  }, function(){
   var el = $(this);
   if (el.is('done')) { return; }
   // on mouseout, stop animation
   clearInterval(timer);
   // fadeIn, just in case the clearInterval breaks the animation
   el.find('.current').stop(true, true).fadeIn('slow');
  });

});
```

Comment: Hi fudgey, thanks for getting back. I will try that and let you know how i get on. The three images are three stages of a sun rising behind hills, so the idea is to give the impression of the sun rising. I  think fading between each image on mouseover but only cycling through once so that it holds on the last image of the sun at its highest point.

Comment: Hi Matt, I've updated my answer and the demo... I hope that helps! :)

Comment: How would I get the animation to stop once it has cycled once and finished on the last image? Could this then hold until page reload? Thanks.

Comment: My updated answer will do this. Basically, the script tries to find the `.next()` image and if it isn't found you know you're on the last image. It then adds a `done` class which stops the cycle.

Comment: Hey Fudgey, you're a total star. Will send you a link to the site once it's up and credit you in the script. Thanks for your help. In my limited experience that looks like lovely clean code.